# How can I make 3 items fill a 6x6 grid with specific rows and columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to model a 6x6 grid, filling up all the columns and row with only 3 elements. The size should be the same as if there was 36 cells but with the 3 cells filling up all the space. For some reason, my cells do not appear to be filling their respective cells and columns.

I found the `span` option although it does not appear to be working properly.

Here is my code:

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    padding: 5px;
}
.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#box1 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 4;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

#box2 {
    grid-column:  5 / 6;
    grid-row: 1 / span 6;
}

#box3 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 4;
    grid-row: span 3 / span 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="grid-item" id="box1">1</div>
<div class="grid-item" id="box2">2</div>
<div class="grid-item" id="box3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the snippet you added is of a single block of 6X6?

Comment: @Manjuboyz I would like the cells to fill up a 6x6 block. Where say box1 is cols: 1-4 and rows: 1 -2, thus taking up 8 blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting grid-template-row/grid-template-column to auto, it's better to use the repeat function, to set up the 6x6 grid.
In order to make the #box2 fill up the entire space, you to make sure that it goes all the way across. The grid inspector in your devtools will show you what lines each element is taking up. So instead of grid-column: span 5/6, it's grid-column span 5/7. The same goes for the #box3, where it's grid-row: span 4/6 instead of grid-row: span 4/5;

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6,1fr);
    background-color: #2196F3;
    padding: 5px;
}
.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#box1 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 4;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

#box2 {
    grid-column:  5 / 7;
    grid-row: 1 / span 6;
}

#box3 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 4;
    grid-row: span 4 / span 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="grid-item" id="box1">1</div>
<div class="grid-item" id="box2">2</div>
<div class="grid-item" id="box3">3</div>
</div>
```